# python:How to print the character from a variable with unicode string

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, web-scraping, scrapy

I practice how to print unicode in python

My question is: how can I edit the code below to translate to unicode 
to print the result just 2014-07-16 ?

```
print 'day: %s  \n' %(releaseday)
```

My original output : **day: [u'2014-07-16']**
The result I want is: **day:2014-07-16**

I'd try `print u'day: %s \n' %(unicode(releaseday))`   And It didn't work

Please teach me Thank you

Comment: Note that `TakeFirst()` is the recommended way to get a first value from an extracted list. If you are using `extract()` to get the list, you can just use `extract_first()` to get the first item or `None` nowadays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `print` gives `[]` in output then probably you have list in `releaseday`

You can:

1) get first element from that list

```
print 'day: %s  \n' % releaseday[0]
```

2) concatenate all elements from list

```
print 'day: %s  \n' % ''.join(releaseday)
```

3) iterate elements from list and print it separatly

```
for x in releaseday:
    print 'day: %s  \n' % x
```

But this is basic knowledge in "pure" python and have nothing to do with scrapy.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a `Scrapy` related question and I assume this is what the [`extract()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector.extract) returned - set [`TakeFirst()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.contrib.loader.processor.TakeFirst) output processor on that specific field:

> Returns the first non-null/non-empty value from the values received,
>   so it’s typically used as an output processor to single-valued fields.

```
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import TakeFirst

class Product(scrapy.Item):
    day = scrapy.Field(output_processor=TakeFirst())
```

Here's what it does on the console:

```
>>> from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import TakeFirst
>>> proc = TakeFirst()
>>> proc([u'2014-07-16'])
u'2014-07-16'
```